# Saved events are not showing in Calendar.app

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to create calendar events using Swift 4 on macOS 10.14

I request access with:

```
self.eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
    print(granted)
})
```

Then I try to create an event with:

```
let event = EKEvent(eventStore: self.eventStore)
event.title = "Help me SO"
event.startDate = Date()
event.endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: Date())
event.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
do {
    try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
} catch let error as NSError { //This is never called
    print("failed to save event with error : \(error)") 
}
print("Saved Event") //This prints
```

Now when I do this, I observe some strange behaviour.

The newly created event **does not** show in the in-built macOS Calendar. It does, however, show on the inbuilt iOS Calendar, hinting that the event *is* being creating and being stored, it's just not showing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: same issue, is it solved?